# Failed to load TinyMCE JS (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce

I'm building a simple document management application but the TinyMCE JS is failing to load (403 error). First I thought this had something to do with file permissions and so I recursively changed everything to 777 (yes, stupid of me but I badly wanted this to work); but this didn't solve anything.

The Chrome console tells me:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Here's my view page which attempts to load the editor:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ankdocs/application/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode: "exact",
    elements : "doc",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,"
    + "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,"
    + "bullist,numlist,outdent,indent",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "link,unlink,anchor,image,separator,"
    +"undo,redo,cleanup,code,separator,sub,sup,charmap",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    height:"350px",
    width:"600px"
});
</script>

<div id="newdoc">

<table>
<tr>
  <td>Document name:</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="docname"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<textarea id="doc" name="doc" rows="20" cols="40">Type here</textarea>

</div>
```

As you can see, nothing fancy here. Somebody told me that perhaps some Apache module is missing (I'm on Ubuntu) but I'm really not sure how to fix that.

Please help!

Let me know if more code is needed.

============ Extended ===========

As requested in the comments, here's the output for search on .htaccess file:

```
root@vostro:~# find /opt/lampp/htdocs/ -iname '*access'
/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/sqlite/.htaccess
/opt/lampp/htdocs/ankdocs/application/cache/.htaccess 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/ankdocs/application/.htaccess 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/ankdocs/system/.htaccess
```

The file ankdocs/application/.htaccess says "Deny from all."
The file ankdocs/system/.htaccess says "Deny from all."

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess file?

Comment: Your error message says server do not have access to that file. So there have to be a rule which is denying access to it.

Comment: I didn't create any .htaccess file. Unless Codeigniter has its own version tucked away somewhere. Where should I check?

Comment: first check in `ankdocs`.

Comment: Yes, I found four:

root@vostro:~# find /opt/lampp/htdocs/ -iname '*access'

/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/sqlite/.htaccess

/opt/lampp/htdocs/ankdocs/application/cache/.htaccess

/opt/lampp/htdocs/ankdocs/application/.htaccess

/opt/lampp/htdocs/ankdocs/system/.htaccess

Now what?

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to format code in comments. :(
The one in ankdocs/application says "Deny from all".

Comment: Add this code at end of your question. That will be easier to understand

Comment: Also add contents of .htaccess file inside `ankdocs` and `ankdocs/application`

Comment: Added to my question. They both say "Deny from all."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder named `assets` inside `ankdocs`. Put your js file there. Actually cut `tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js` and put in `assets/js` and change

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ankdocs/assets/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"/>
```

Comment: I just realized my directory structure is different! But anyway, the new arrangement is also not working. The script tag now says: 

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http: //localhost/ankdocs/application/assets/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"/> (added an extra space after colon to avoid creating a link here)

and the js is at ankdocs/application/assets/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js

Comment: File inside application is not accessible. Either remove the .htaccess from application (which is very bad thing to do) or relocate your js file as described in answer.

Comment: Ah! So stupid of me not being able to follow instructions carefully. Let me try it and report back.

Comment: 403 error vanished, hurray! Thank you so much for the patience! :) :)
Now the problem is I don't see the editor, but perhaps that can be handled in a later question. Thanks a lot, really!! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you put the js folder inside the application folder which is used by codeigniter
try moving the js folder outside the application folder 
i think codeigniter is trying to resolve the path to a controller which does not exist

and change your JavaScript reference to the new path somthing like that

`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//localhost/ankdocs/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"/>`

good luck and Merry Xmas